# Turing machine state with 2 "values"?

Tags: turing-machines

$Q=\left\{q_{0}, q_{1}\right\} \times\{0,1, \cup\} \times\{0,1, \cup\}$

What does this mean ? Is it just for saving values in a state?

Comment: It's the set of all triples obtained by picking one element of each of the three sets. No more, no less.

Comment: Where does this show up? What are your symbol's meanings? How does your definition of Turing machne read?